# Many-to-many relationship not working in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am working on WCF service in which I want to return user object (Rolename, Userid, EmailId, Password, UserName etc...) and I want to store data also in my table as per requirement.

These are my SQL Server 2008 tables:

- `UserMaster`: `UserId, Username` etc....
- `RoleMaster`: `Roleid, RoleName`
- `UserInRole`: `UserId, RoleId`

Now when I have created edmx file (database first entity framework) for these tables then in my edmx file that is context file there is no dbset of userinrole as because there is no class file of userinrole.

But I am not using edmx file as because we can't write Datamember Keyword for serialization because i am returning my result in json. I have created all class file by my own.

My class file structure is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class UserDetails
{
   [DataMember]
   public int Id { get; set; }
           .
           .
   public virtual ICollection<RoleMaster> RoleMasters { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class RoleMaster
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
        .
        .
}

[DataContract]
public class UserInRole
{
   [DataMember]
   public int UserId { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public int RoleId { get; set; }

   public virtual UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
   public virtual RoleMaster RoleMaster { get; set; }
}
```

I want to fetch roles of those user whose emaild and password matches in userdetails table.

This is my query:

```
 var user = context.UserDetails.Where(u => u.Username == "john" && u.Password == "123").FirstOrDefault();
```

This is my fluent api:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetails>()
            .HasMany(i => i.RoleMasters)
            .WithMany(u => u.UserDetails)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UserInRole");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            });
```

This is the error I get:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'UserInRole' has
>   no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'UserInRole' is based on type 'UserInRole' that has no keys defined.

Can anybody tell me whats the problem?

Do I need to specify all primary keys in fluent api??

Comment: Yes, `EntityType 'UserInRole' has no key defined` this means that you have to define ID in the `UserInRole` table.

Comment: u mean primary key??